# Calculating partial derivatives for this particular function

Tags: partial-derivative

For $s,r>0$, we have a function $V(s,r)= (gs^2+r(1-g^2-2\ln s))/2$.

The paper that I am reading says that $V_s=gs$. However, shouldn't it be $gs-r/s$?

This is a highly cited paper, and hence I'm unable to understand how it could have such a simple error

Comment: Yup, it's a simple error, indeed.

Comment: Please, what is the reference of that paper? (To double-check whether you misread something)

Comment: @AnneBauval- The paper is here- https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374139

Comment: $g$ is not a constant. It is a function of $(s,r).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374139):

> $V(s,r)= (gs^2+r(1-g^2-2\ln s))/2$, where
> $g(r,s)=h^{-1}(r/s^2)$ and [...] $(h^{-1})'(t)=\frac1{2th^{-1}(t)-1}.$

Therefore,
$$g_s=\frac{-2r/s^3}{2(r/s^2)g-1}=\frac{r/s}{s^2/2-rg}$$
and
$$\begin{align}V_s&=gs-r/s+(s^2/2-rg)g_s\\
&=gs-r/s+r/s\\
&=gs.\end{align}$$